# Spring WS Client TLS support

Tags: ssl, spring-ws

I need to change a current Spring-ws client implementation to use TLS security instead of SSL. To be honest, i didn't to anything special to enable SSL, just standard spring-ws connectors and required key stores, that's all.

My question, to enable TLS specifically on a spring-ws client, what should I do ?

Comment: Spring-ws does not define if the connection is secured or not. This is the role of web container (tomcat for example). What are you using ?

Comment: i think i wrote it wrong. Im the client side and 3rd party server side ws impelentation will be changing sec. to TLS. What i wonder is, as client side, do i nees to change anything?? I used spring-ws on client side.